# Linear Mixed Model Failing to Converge

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, convergence, mediation

I am attempting to run a Multilevel Mediation in R with overtime data (4 time points, 50 participants). I was hoping to create two new columns for each outcome and predictor variable, a baseline column (to be able to look at their scores before the experiment) and an average column of time 2-4. To do this, I spread my data from long to wide, created a baseline column and calculated an average column for my time 2-4, leaving me with two new columns.

My first problem that I ran into was that it was impossible to gather it back into long without filling in the values, so I used a `full_join` to accomplish this. This essentially filled in all 4 time points in the T2-4 column with that average that was created above. I did the same thing for the baseline column. 
For example:

```
subject_id    stress_T2-4
A1            5.76
A1            5.76
A1            5.76
A1            5.76
A2            3.75
A2            3.75
```

Once everything was joined, I then tried to run my models using the `lmer` function in the "lme4" package. To do the mediation with the overtime data, I am following the typical mixed models approach of building up the models slowly, like so:

Intercept only model of y ~ 1

Random intercept model y ~ 1 + random participant/time effects

Random intercept model y ~ 1 + random participant/time effects + X fixed effect predicting Y

Random intercept model y ~ 1 + random participant/time effects + X fixed predicting M

Random intercept model y ~ 1 + random participant/time effects + X fixed + M fixed predicting Y

I am trying to use the new variable I created representing the t2-4 as the outcome (y) but when I do this I get three convergence errors. I am fairly new to mixed models so I am a little lost on how to interpret these errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.86262 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
3: In as_lmerModLT(model, devfun) :
  Model may not have converged with 1 eigenvalue close to zero: 1.3e-11
```

Q1: Am I going about separating time points and then generating averages correctly?

Q2: Am I getting these convergence errors because of the repeated averages in the rows?

Q3: Any suggestions for how I could be doing this better?

Comment: multiple observations with exactly the same response will definitely be a problem -- it implies that the residual variation is exactly zero, which causes a bunch of other problems.  I have answered similar questions *somewhere* on CV and/or `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` but don't know how long it will take me to find them ...

Comment: e.g. see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2015q3/023748.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link @Ben Bolker!

Comment: You could plot the results based on various optimizers. If the results are consistent across optimizers, they would be more trustworthy. A function and a code-through is available at: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2021/a-new-function-to-plot-convergence-diagnostics-from-lme4-allfit/